# Is it possible for search terms to appear in the search bar of an iPad just from going to a "bad" website?

Tags: ipad, search

I was told that some search terms appeared in the search bar of an iPad because that person had gone to a "bad" website and the terms must have come from that visit.

Answer (score 2):

The search bar should only offer suggestions based on your website history, your bookmarks, or searches that you have typed in and hit enter for.

It won't scour the pages you have been to, looking for related terms.

Comment: are you saying that a website address would not show up in the search bar simply because a person had gone to another website? say, if I went to cnn.com, the search term for a website mentioned on cnn.com would not appear in the search bar?

Comment: Correct. CNN.com could potentially show up, but money.com won't just because CNN links to it.

Comment: otherwise… with only 6 degrees of separation, you'd have autocomplete for every web site in the world ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin You're right. That's funny.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the potential for typos to generate irritating additions to your search.

Imagine you frequently visit `porkchop.com` [I have no idea if it actually exists, that's irrelevant] yet one day you accidentally typo `pornchop` & hit enter… and contra to all expectations that site actually exists.

Afterwards, every time you type `por` Safari will show you both sites as potentials.

I once typo'd something [I don't know what I typed, but I meant to type `home`] into Google Maps so it would show me the route…
…for 3 months afterwards until it eventually fell off the popular list, the first option it always wanted me to go to was the Houses of Parliament at Westminster...

Comment: I understand that possibility, but apparently it was a bad cookie that showed up.